# How do I make water tank control circuit?

Tags: home-automation, automation

[image: Water tank]
[image: Water tank's sketch]
[image: Water tank filling time interval, Start/Stop]

I would like to make electronic circuit to control water tank. Its works expected as below:

- Once water inside the tank is lower than its minimum level, then the mechanical sensor A will trigger to activate the electronic circuit C to power electric water pump connected to it. Electric water pump would be connected by relay, to make it separate from the electric circuit.
- Once the circuit is triggered by sensor A, it have to be **REMAIN ON** even the mechanical floating sensor no more pulling the trigger. That is required to make sure the pump motor keep working to pump water till the tank is full.
- Once the water reaches the maximum or full level, the mechanical sensor B will trigger the circuit to power off the water pump motor (to power of the relay).
- If during the filling water to the tank power grid is OFF, then it will be assume as the sensor B as active, the pump is powered off.

My question:

- How to make the circuit active (water pump is working) after the mechanical sensor A is no more working as it start float.
- How do I make the circuit? Motor is put separate and controlled through relay.

For this purpose, circuit is avoided to use logic gate. Electric power to the circuit could be DC or AC, but preferred is AC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of controlling the pump I can think of is as in this schematic.  Once the lower switch is activated, the relay will latch on.  Only when the upper switch is broken will the relay switch off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEUkeC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I tried to understand your circuit, but I think it is not working. Say, when the lower switch is **SWITCHED ON**, then relay will activated to power the pump to fill the tank. Not long after started to fill the tank, the floating sensor A will become **FLOATING**, which will deactivated the switch (**SWITCHED OFF**). As far as I know, there is no memory of relay to keep it **REMAIN ON** when the lower switched is off. Am I wrong? Kindly more explanation.

Comment: @AirCraftLover The second pair of contacts is bypassing the lower switch, therefore keeping power on the relay even when the switch opens.

Comment: The lower switch is not connected to the DC power on the right side. How it activate the relay? Where it derived its magnetic force?

Comment: @AirCraftLover Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you understand how the schematic would work in theory?  Is there something about your limit switches that you need to describe in more detail?

Comment: @AirCraftLover  Can you see that when both limit switched are closed that the relay will switch on/  Then even if the lower limit switch is opened, the relay will remain on due to the relay contacts bypassing the switch?

Comment: Sorry about my last comment. But I still don't know how it work.

Comment: OK, the lower switch will trigger the relay active as the upper switch is closed. But then, when the water tank is full, what is then will trigger to open the circuit? Upper circuit? OK, you may say it, sensor B will trigger the upper switch to be OFF (open), to terminate the pump. In this case, both lower circuit and upper circuit are now OFF (or OPENED). Then, when the situation repeated water began empty and sensor A activated lower switch (while upper switch also OFF), then what will trigger upper switch?

Comment: As the level in the tank starts to drop, the top limit switch will close.  The relay won't activate until the lower limit switch also closes.  The pump will run until the tank is full, then the upper switch will open and turn the pump off again.  Repeat as necessary.

Comment: I started to understand the logic, hope I will get it.

Comment: Just after water began to fill the tank, lower switch will then be **OFF (or OPENED)**. At that time, the upper switch's status is **ON (or CLOSED)** (since the water inside the tank began drained). Just immediately after the pump filling water up to the tank, the lower switch will be **OFF (OPENED)** but upper switch is remain **ON (or CLOSED)**. Until then the tank is full, the mechanical sensor will floating and will cause the upper switch to **OFF (OPENED)**. Now, both the switch are **OFF (OPENED)**. Until then water began drained, upper switch become **ON (CLOSED)** again. Is like that?

Comment: I believe, it is the logic. But then, what is the two switching on the relay? Why need two and not only one?

Comment: I believe you have the correct understanding.  You need one pair of contacts in the relay to switch the pump on.  The other pair of contacts is used to keep the relay switched on while the water level is not triggering either limit switch. i.e. until the tank is full.

Comment: OK my Friend, thank you very much for you have patiently explained. I credited your answer and I accepted.